# Change count on card based on filter values

Tags: powerbi, reporting

I have a card that has shows the count of all the projects. There are slicer drop downs like:

-Employee Name

-Practice (like Finance, DevOps, AppDev)

I am trying to change the count based on the filter I have choose. For example if i have no filter selected the count should be total projects. If I select an employee name the count should show the number of projects the employee worked on, similarly for practice if I select a practice the count of projects should change and only the porjects that fall under a certain practice should be counted.

The data comes from three tables:

1. Project table (has the project related details like name, id etc.)
2. Employee table (has the employee related details)
3. Resource table (this holds different practices)

There is a 1:1 mapping with bi-directional filtering betwen Project and Employee table.

There is a 1:* mapping with bi-directional filtering between Employee and Resource table.

No direct relationship between Resource and Project table.

Is there a way to achieve this in single card?

I tried this to filter project by employee. I have one filter for name of employees and the ProjectCount is a measure that counts the total projects. This doesn't work. Where am I going wrong?

```
ProjectCountByEmp = 
VAR proj = Values('DPM_Project'[ProjectName])
RETURN
CALCULATE(DPM_Project[ProjectCount],ALL('DPM_MST_Employee'[FirstName]),proj)
```

Comment: Yes, that's how slicers are designed to work. Are you not getting the result you expect?

Comment: You explained the slicers and model design seems to be normal, Sorry what is the actual question?

Comment: edited the question.